# no such table: reward (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO reward(Reward2,Reward1,Reward3) VALUES (?,?,?)

Tags: java, sqlite, android-studio

Hello I'm a student and doing my final year project using sql and android studio. I want to create multiple table and I've trying to follow the example but it doesn't work. the error was no table created. Here my coding

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
package com.example.multipletable;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MultipleTable";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
    private static final String TABLE_1 = "register";
    private static final String TABLE_2 = "activity";
    private static final String TABLE_3 = "reward";

    String table_1 = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_1+" (matricno TEXT PRIMARY KEY, password TEXT, email TEXT)";
    String table_2 = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_2+" (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, t_question TEXT, date DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE)";
    String table_3 = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_3+" (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, badge_green TEXT, badge_purple TEXT, badge_maroon TEXT)";


    public DatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(table_1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Current version"+db.getVersion());

        for (int version=oldVersion+1; version<=newVersion; version++) {
            switch (version) {
                case 2:
                    db.execSQL(table_2);

                case 3:
                    db.execSQL(table_3);
            }
        }





//        Log.e("DATABASE VERSION", db.getVersion()+" ");
//
//        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_1);
//        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_2);
//        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_3);
//
//        onCreate(db);

    }

    public boolean insert(String matNo, String pswd, String email) {
        SQLiteDatabase db_1 = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues1 = new ContentValues();
        contentValues1.put("MatricNo", matNo);
        contentValues1.put("Password", pswd);
        contentValues1.put("Email", email);
        db_1.insert(TABLE_1, null, contentValues1);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean insert2(String question) {
        SQLiteDatabase db_2 = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues2 = new ContentValues();
        contentValues2.put("Question", question);
        contentValues2.put("Date", getDate());
        db_2.insert(TABLE_2, null, contentValues2);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean insert3(String green, String purple, String maroon) {
        SQLiteDatabase db_3 = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues3 = new ContentValues();
        contentValues3.put("Reward1", green);
        contentValues3.put("Reward2", purple);
        contentValues3.put("Reward3", maroon);
        db_3.insert(TABLE_3, null, contentValues3);
        return true;
    }

    private String getDate() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }
}
```

**MainActiviti.java**

```
package com.example.multipletable;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText name, pswd, email;
    Button btn_1;
    DatabaseHelper db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        name = findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
        pswd = findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
        email = findViewById(R.id.txt_email);
        btn_1 = findViewById(R.id.btn_next_1);
        db = new DatabaseHelper(this);


        btn_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String person = name.getText().toString();
                String pass = pswd.getText().toString();
                String mail = email.getText().toString();

                Boolean insert = db.insert(person, pass, mail);
                if (insert==true) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data 1 saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
                    startActivity(intent1);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data 1 error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Activity2.java**

```
package com.example.multipletable;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText question;
    Button btn2;
    DatabaseHelper db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);

        question = findViewById(R.id.txt_question);
        btn2 = findViewById(R.id.btn_next_2);
        db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String ques = question.getText().toString();

                Boolean insert2 = db.insert2(ques);
                if (insert2==true) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data 2 saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(Activity2.this, Activity3.class);
                    startActivity(intent2);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data 2 error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Activity3.java**

```
package com.example.multipletable;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Activity3 extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText green, purple, maroon;
    Button btn3;
    DatabaseHelper db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_3);

        green = findViewById(R.id.txt_green);
        purple = findViewById(R.id.txt_purple);
        maroon = findViewById(R.id.txt_maroon);
        btn3 = findViewById(R.id.btn_next_3);
        db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String grn = green.getText().toString();
                String ppl = purple.getText().toString();
                String mrn = maroon.getText().toString();

                Boolean insert3 = db.insert3(grn, ppl, mrn);
                if (insert3==true) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data 3 saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent3 = new Intent(Activity3.this, FINISH.class);
                    startActivity(intent3);
                }
                else  {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data 3 error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Can you please help me find the solution and tell me what is wrong :(

Comment: As error said you didn't create 'reward' table when try to insert something inside. Take a look on room persistence https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room. It's more modern way to work with SQLite and also more simpler for junior developers.

Comment: Check your manifest. If there is this line: `android:allowBackup="true"` cjange it to `false`. Then uninstall the app from the device and rerun.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where your error comes from but, I am assuming its on launch or when you insert the data.

I create my SQL table like below.

However, I did encounter a really annoying issue of if I change my table my app would crash as it would not find it. The fix was I needed to uninstall the app on my phone before uploading the application from android studio to my phone. Hope it helps

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME ="TESTING.db";
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLE_1 = "T1";
    public static final String TABLE_2 = "T2";
    public static final String TABLE_3  = "T3";

    public static final String COL1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL2 = "D1";
    public static final String COL3 = "D2";
    public static final String COL4 = "D3";
    public static final String COL5 = "D4";
    public static final String COL6 = "D5";
    public static final String COL7 = "D6";
    public static final String COL8 = "time";


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        // creating required tables
        String Created_TABLE_1= "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_1 + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                "D1 TEXT, D2 TEXT, D3, TEXT, D4 TEXT, D5 TEXT, D6 TEXT, TIME TEXT)";
        String Created_TABLE_2= "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_2 + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                "D1 TEXT, D2 TEXT, D3, TEXT, D4 TEXT, D5 TEXT, D6 TEXT, TIME TEXT)";
        String Created_TABLE_3= "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_3 + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                "D1 TEXT, D2 TEXT, D3, TEXT, D4 TEXT, D5 TEXT, D6 TEXT, TIME TEXT)";


        db.execSQL(Created_TABLE_1);
        db.execSQL(Created_TABLE_2);
        db.execSQL(Created_TABLE_3);

    }
```

Ps Stay safe all

Answer (score -1):

Thank you Eugene Troyanskii, forpas and Thomas Morris. I've solved the problem. Supposed to be assign with correct name for column according to create table statement at inserting data code, but I write it different.

Again thanks guys!

Comment: This should have been said in a comment, not an answer to the question.